# What am I doing wrong when using string.join in my code?

Tags: c#

I have the code below, which I need to separate the result with ", ". I have so far used different methods because whenever I try to use String.Join, it doesn't work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace _5._PrintEvenNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToList();

            var numbers = new Queue<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (input[i] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    numbers.Enqueue(input[i]);
                }
            }

            while (numbers.Any())
            {
                Console.Write(string.Join(", ", numbers.Dequeue()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result should be "2, 4, 6" for example. Currently it prints it "246"

Comment: Sorry. I had the code updated a bit so it prints every dequeued number. I am typing in(with the current code), 2 4 6 OR 246 and both are resulting in 246, instead of 2, 4, 6

Comment: Numbers.Dequeue takes only one number from queue, so string.Join does not have anything to join.

Comment: You should not put it in loop, just pass a collection to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace

```
while (numbers.Any())
{
   Console.Write(string.Join(", ", numbers.Dequeue()));
}
```

with

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", numbers));
```

Unless you really need to dequeue.

Comment: UPDATE: now that you've updated the answer, it actually works. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it was because i blindly copied the line.